# tkinter how to open 2 or more root windows in different locations on the screen

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have written a task reminder application in python and tkinter. It schedules the reminders using the Task Scheduler. The reminders are displayed by a small GUI program in a certain location on the screen. My problem is that the reminders overlap each other. When multiple reminders appear, how can I make them appear in distinct positions? **Please note that I am referring to a separate invocation of the GUI program for each reminder.**

The situation is similar to opening, say, multiple copies of the calculator program. They open in distinct locations on the screen. How does it happen?

The program that creates the reminders is as follows -

```
from tkinter import *
import shelve
import sys

def showTask(parent, key):
    parent.title('Reminder')
    parent.geometry('300x100-0-40')
    parent.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    parent.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    shelfFile = shelve.open('C:\\Users\\hp\\pypgms\\data\\tasks')
    message = shelfFile[key]['name']
    shelfFile.close()

    Label(parent, text=message).grid(padx=20, pady=20, sticky=NW)
    btn = Button(parent, text='Ok', command=parent.quit)
    btn.grid(pady=5)
    btn.bind('<Return>', lambda e: parent.quit())

key = sys.argv[1]
root = Tk()
showTask(root, key)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter windows have a convenient method called `geometry()` to define their size and position on the screen following [this format](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/geometry.html):

```
root.geometry('250x150+300+300')   # width=250, height=150, position=(300,300)
```

See below how you can use it to open reminder windows next to one another:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class MainApp():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.reminderWindows = []
        self.button = tk.Button(self.root, text="New reminder", 
                                command=self.open_new_reminder)
        self.button.pack()

    def open_new_reminder(self):
        reminder = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        self.reminderWindows.append(reminder)
        windowNumber = len(self.reminderWindows)
        reminder.geometry("100x120+{}+200".format(str(150*windowNumber)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = tk.Tk()
    MainApp(app)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Here your reminder windows are part of the same invocation of the application. But what about different invocations? How will a reminder window and its geometry method know that there are previous reminder windows?

Comment: If your reminder windows are defined in a separate file, just replace `reminder = tk.Toplevel(self.root)` above by `reminder = (...)` where `(...)` is the reminder window created by your code. A controller class like `MainApp` is the best way to keep track of your reminder windows.

Comment: I did not understand `reminder = (...)`. What exactly would I replace `(...)` with? In my case, there is no separate file for the reminders. They are all created by the same program which, therefore, gets invoked several times.

Comment: Each invocation of the program is with a different command-line argument, causing it to display a different reminder message.

Comment: I see, can you please edit your question to add the code of the program you use to create a new reminder window? That will make it easier to help...